# Помогите, пожалуйста, убрать границу внизу блока div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу убрать серую полосу внизу блока Подарочные наборы. Пытался играться с высотой, margin-padding, border выставлял на 0, ничего в голову не приходит больше, не могу понять кто хулиганит)

Прикладываю код, остальные блоки однотипны, внешней обертки нет. Так же если по коду что-то режет глаза ругайте, учусь, буду благодарен критике.

На всякий случай полностью тут: https://jsfiddle.net/wm4ynzvb/

HTML

```
 <div class="nabory">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="categories__names__cover"> 
                <p class="categories__names__cover__text">Подарочные наборы</p>   
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .categories__names__cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 401px;
    height: 160px;   //пробовал ставить меньше-больше, не помогло, высота картинки 161px
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin-left: -35px;
}

.nabory {
      background: url(../img/nabory.jpg) ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px; //пробовал ставить меньше-больше, не помогло, высота картинки 161px
    margin-bottom: -8px;  //у каждой картинки черная граница есть, отступ нужен что бы они были внахлест
}

.categories__names__cover__text {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto-Thin';
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-left: 85px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш фидл несколько отличается от картинки

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать примерно такую шнягу

```
border-bottom:0px solid black !important;
```

Comment: не помогло, а если поставить border-bottom:10px solid black; то граница будет после этой серой линии (добавил еще картинку наверх), то есть зазор между границей и контентом, вроде это и есть padding, но выставление его на ноль то же не помогает

Comment: Жаль, что не помогло.